# What happened to @JsonSerialize in Jackson 1.9?

Tags: java, scala, jackson

Looks like `@JsonSerialize` annotation has gone missing in the newer versions of Jackson. Can't find what happened to them. Wanted to do the following in Scala:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=classOf[YourSerializer])
@JsonDeSerialize(using=classOf[YourDeserializer])
```

I imported `import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate._`. When I go to compile, I get the following `not found: type JsonSerialize`.

Where did it all go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was bundled in a new package.

`import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate._`